# AttributeError: 'CollectionReference' object has no attribute 'orderBy'

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to order a firestore collection by the field name, but it's giving me this error: AttributeError: 'CollectionReference' object has no attribute 'orderBy'.

My code:

```
participants_ref = db.collection("participants")
docs = participants_ref.orderBy("name").stream()
```

In case this helps, I've also printed out participants_ref and I get the following:
<google.cloud.firestore_v1.collection.CollectionReference object at 0x0000021C9EAB7F40>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data#order_and_limit_data), the method you're looking for is `order_by`.  Be sure to switch the code language tab to "Python" to see the correct usage.

```
docs = participants_ref.order_by("name").stream()
```

Also see the [python API documentation for CollectionReference](https://googleapis.dev/python/firestore/latest/collection.html).

Comment: Wow I feel like a fool :") The reference I used was mostly similar to the python package so I didn't realise this was different. Thanks!